# Join two queries to return articles and its likes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle and need help with the following:
I have the following query which returns a list of articles:

```
SELECT      LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID, 
            LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC, 
            LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT, 
            LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT,
            LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, 
            LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL, 
            LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID,
            MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
FROM        RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER     LEADERSHIP 
INNER JOIN  RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE            MEDIA       ON  LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
WHERE (LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) IN 
(
    SELECT  LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, MAX(LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
    FROM    RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER 
    GROUP BY LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
)
ORDER BY LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT DESC
```

I also have to implement the total likes for each article, which I can get with this query:

```
SELECT  LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID, 
        COUNT(*) TOTAL_LIKES 
FROM    RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER     LEADERSHIP1, 
        RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERS_LIKES         LIKES1 
WHERE   LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID = LIKES1.LDRSHP_ID 
group by LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID
```

Now I need a single SQL statement by combining the above two queries to return all the articles along with the total likes for each article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by doing the LEFT OUTER JOIN the 2 sql's:

```
SELECT A.LDRSHP_ID
    , A.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC
    , A.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT
    , A.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT
    , A.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
    , A.MEDIA_URL
    , A.ARTCL_SRC_ID
    , A.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP 
    , B.TOTAL_LIKES
FROM
    (
            SELECT LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID
                   , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                  , LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL
                  , LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID
                  , MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP 
              FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP 
              INNER JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA 
                  ON (LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF) 
              WHERE (LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
              IN (SELECT LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                    , MAX(LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
                  FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER 
                  GROUP BY LDRSHP_ATHR_NM) 
      ) A 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
              SELECT LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID
              , COUNT(*) TOTAL_LIKES 
              FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP1
              , RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERS_LIKES LIKES1 
              WHERE LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID = LIKES1.LDRSHP_ID 
              group by LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID
      ) B
              ON (A.LDRSHP_ID=B.LDRSHP_ID)
      ORDER BY A.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` on the `likes` table as well in the first query and get the `count` of likes.

```
SELECT  LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID, 
        LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC, 
        LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT, 
        LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT,
        LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, 
        LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL, 
        LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID,
        MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP,
        count(likes.*) total_likes
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP 
INNER JOIN  RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA
ON LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF
LEFT JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERS_LIKES LIKES
ON LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID = LIKES.LDRSHP_ID
WHERE (LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) IN 
(
SELECT LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, MAX(LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER 
GROUP BY LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
)
GROUP BY LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID, 
         LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC, 
         LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT, 
         LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT,
         LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM, 
         LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL, 
         LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID,
         MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP
ORDER BY LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT DESC
```

Comment: You probably want to left join to LEADERS_LIKES and `count(LIKES.LDRSHP_ID)` instead of `count(*)`. That way you don't prune away any of the LEDERSHIP and MEDIA data when there are no likes.

Comment: This gives me only one row and also       LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT is a clob datatype so cannot be compared.

Comment: try the modified query.